# htaccess redirection help needed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a dynamic url `domain.com/product/Paper_Bags/Merchandise_Bags_-_Matte_Colors/6_25__X_9_25_/Misty_Grey?7`. Which when called need to redirect to `domain.com/paper-merchandise-bags-plain-white/`

I am using the condition and the rule as

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Misty_Grey http://domain.com/paper-merchandise-bags-plain-white/? [R=301,L]
```

But its not working. Can Someone help me to solve this issue.

If i use `RedirectMatch  ^(.*)/Misty_Grey http://domain.com/paper-merchandise-bags-plain-white/`
Its getting redirected to `http://domain.com/paper-merchandise-bags-plain-white/?7`
Is there any way to remove the ?7 so tha the querystring will not be visible

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands,

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/product/Paper_Bags/Merchandise_Bags_-_Matte_Colors/6_25__X_9_25_/Misty_Grey?7 http://domain.com/paper-merchandise-bags-plain-white/?
```